# Is Python's time.monotonic() consistent across multiple threads?

Tags: python-3.x, time, python-multithreading

Python's documentation for [`time.monotonic()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic) states:

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a monotonic clock, i.e. a clock that cannot go backwards. The clock is not affected by system clock updates. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.
>
> *New in version 3.3.*
>
> *Changed in version 3.5:* The function is now always available and always system-wide.

Does the last sentence imply that for Python >= 3.5 the values returned by `time.monotonic()` can be safely used and compared across multiple threads?

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem and it seems **NO** , getting around 10 microseconds difference across threads.

I'm on Linux, Python 3.7.5, Kernel 5.3.0-40-generic , CPU AMD Ryzen 5 3600

Comment: How did you measure this? 10 microseconds is well on the scale of jitter from using queues or stdout to collect results.

Comment: Both threads stored the result of the monotonic() function into dictionaries. one sends an ICMP ping, the other recieves it. on pinging localhost ,the monotonic result of the receiver was 10 microseconds before the sender sent it. the monotonic call was before the actual packet send and on the receiving side after the select call.

Comment: This was measured in a process with multiple threads or in multiple processes (multiprocessing)?

Comment: threads. for different processes the answer to this question is obviously no.

Answer (score 2):

No.

On MacOS X, `time.monotonic()` resets between different Python interpreters, starting at 0. So comparing values between processes is meaningless.

On Linux, it's more consistent; I was able to pickle timers using `time.monotonic()` and pass them between multiprocessing workers and get useful results. But on my Ubuntu system `time.monotonic()` returns a number of seconds less than `uptime`, so it must reset under some conditions.

Comment: The OP asked for threads, not processes.